# Activity indicator loading before Wkwebview in objective c

Tags: objective-c

i am using wkwebview and loading an url in objective c. i  need to show activity indicator before loading wkwebview. is there any delegate methods for wkwebview?

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    [spinner setCenter:CGPointMake(160,124)];
    [self.view addSubview:spinner];
    spinner.tag = 100;
    [spinner startAnimating];


    _homeWebView.opaque = true;
   // http://ispatialtec.com/birdathon.php
    _homeWebView.userInteractionEnabled = true;
    [_homeWebView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.adbirdathon.ae/Birdathon/index.html"]]];
    [spinner stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: The web view has a loading property that's true while loading. It also has a navigation delegate that sends https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wknavigationdelegate/1455629-webview?language=objc once the request is complete

Comment: is it possible to show activity indicator before view will appear get called? because its taking time  when webview is loading in view will appear...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is the `WKNavigationDelegate` method

`- (void)webView:(WKWebView *)webView didFinishNavigation:(WKNavigation *)navigation`

So remove your spinner there.